# create postgres database if it does not exist on docker-compose start up

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-changeme}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres:/data/postgres
    onrun:
      psql -h=localhost -P=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD} -U=${POSTGRES_USER} -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'premiership'" | grep -q 1 || psql -h=localhost -P=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}-U=${POSTGRES_USER}c "CREATE DATABASE premiership"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The above does not work because there is no onrun in docker-compose services.

All I want to do is create a database if it does not exist but this is insanely difficult because I don't know when the service is up.

Also it is not easy to do this in postgres. I tried mapping a volume so that an initdb.sql is ran:

```
volumes:
   - postgres:/data/postgres
   - ./initdb/1_schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_schema.sql
```

1_schema.sql looks like this:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE datname='premiership'';
    IF datname='
premiership' 
        THEN CREATE DATABASE premiership PASSWORD 'test';
    END IF;
```

THe database is not created and when I run `docker-compose logs` I don't see anything about running the script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried setting `POSTGRES_DB` variable in your `docker-compose.yml` environment ?

```yaml
 image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-changeme}
      POSTGRES_DB: premiership
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
```

see https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres :

> `POSTGRES_DB`
>
> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different
>   name for the default database that is created when the image is first
>   started. If it is not specified, then the value of `POSTGRES_USER` will
>   be used.

Comment: thank you sir.  Does PG_DATA mean I don;t have to map the volume?

Comment: `PGDATA` is the location inside the container for the database files. If you have no particular reason to change it, you should just leave the default `/var/lib/postgresql/data` and replace your volume mapping with `postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Have you tried to remove both the container and the volume, and restart the service ? You can do it with `docker-compose down -v` and then `docker-compose up`

Comment: This comment is definitely useful. Having said that, I'm observing that this does not create my database with that name with version 3.9 of docker compose on windows. It is creating a database with my username which is the fall back as you mentioned above.

Comment: @max even I face the same behavior, database is created with the username. were you able to resolve that ?